# PHP if variable == variable with commas exact match

Tags: php, html

I have this code:

```
<option  <?php if ($var == 1 ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="1">name</option>
```

this will set my dropdown box to the correct selection.

However I also have this option in the list:

```
<option  <?php if ($var == '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9' ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9">name2</option>
```

The second one does not work - it takes only the first number "1" and then the dropdown box with value 1 is selected.

How can I match the $var to the exact '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9' variable?

Comment: I think you want to be using strict equality here...

Comment: How are you using this? Can you post the code section you are using this in?

Comment: What's value of `$var` in second example? Also do you want to check if `$var` is either 1, or 2, or etc?

Comment: == should work as it's treated as a string. Use `"` instead of `'` and then it will be treated literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the strict equality operator:

```
$a === $b; // returns true ONLY if both the value and type of $a and $b match.
```

But I do believe that you should re-think the input value architecture. Using complex strings as values is rarely justified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strcmp function. More info:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php